# Can't find reason for error in GridView

Tags: android

I'm testing an example of a GridView at Android Developers webpage, but I get a couple of error, despite that I have copy and paste the code! Link below to the example. What could I have done wrong? Preciate some help! Thanks!

[image]

The error message: Multiple markers at this line
    - OnItemClickListener cannot be resolved to a type
    - The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView is not 
     applicable for the arguments (new OnItemClickListener(){})

[GridView example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html#example)

EDIT: All the code

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickSelectedListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
}
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
 import android.widget.GridView;
 import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
};
}
```

Comment: do you try with (new View.OnItemClickListener){

Comment: Press Ctrl + Shift + o

Comment: That helped a little, but still red line below setOn...

Comment: What is the reason for down voting my question?

Comment: Any updates and were you able to run it ?

Comment: can u post the whole code

Comment: It seems to work now after I copy and paste the code again

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `gridView.setOnItemSelectedListener`

This works fine for me

Comment: No, I still have a red line below the line! I got rid of the red line below View, because I missed the import thing.

Answer (score -1):

Could you import the following classes ?

```
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.view.View;
```

and then save the file. An. equivalent on eclipse would be ctrl shift o and then ctrl s

Comment: Yes! import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

Comment: Could you clean and re-build your project ?

Answer (score -1):

Your need to import the this

```
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.view.View;

       or
```

use BaseAdapter